# Generation of Windows forms from databases

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation

Is there any tools using which I can use to create Windows forms from selecting database table only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems related.

[Is there any framework for Windows Forms, DB driven application development/prototyping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457365/is-there-any-framework-for-windows-forms-db-driven-application-development-proto)

Answer (score 1):

[Telerik ORM](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx) let's you create CRUD froms selecting only the table in the database.