# Automatically import table columns into form design

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

So far, I found C# on SQL Server impressively easy to develop with (when relying on the IDEs to walk you through completion).

So it comes as no surprise that I expect a feature that may or may not be available with Visual Studio 2010 & SQL Server 2008 Express:

Instead of manually dragging `TextBox`es from the ToolBar into the Windows Form, then typing their names, etc. to associate them with a fields/columns in a table... is it possible to tell Visual Studio to automatically populate the form with **all** columns from a particular table?

If so, how does one accomplishes that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at DataBinding to do this easily.  Add your database as a new DataSource for your project, then you can drag parts of it to your form.

See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial) for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You may need to explore .Net Reflection a bit, using which you can build dynamic forms application.

Actually there is something similar for Web called LightSwitch (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/lightswitch.aspx)

Comment: Try this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457365/is-there-any-framework-for-windows-forms-db-driven-application-development-prot

Comment: Reflection certainly could work, but it's kindof overkill for this, and wouldn't really work well with the designer.